# Tumblr - Make image posts responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tumblr

I was able to figure out what is to do in order to make video embeds responsive (minor add in the css style sheet and some adds on the html coding - fine).

I was not able to figure that out for pictures. I used to do Tumblr post changes in html and the embed of the picture looks like this:

```
</p><figure class="tmblr-full" data-orig-height="332" data-orig-width="1170"><img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/fbfec10da6006e67fce4be8f5d7343ff/tumblr_inline_pl7kmovAHp1svrcsh_540.png" data-orig-height="332" data-orig-width="1170" alt="image"></figure><p>
```

Can someone please help to guide me through that? I'm not interested to photosets or something like that. The image just shall resize once it is mobile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-width` option for your `img`s like this:

```
<img src="https://66.media.tumblr.com/fbfec10da6006e67fce4be8f5d7343ff/tumblr_inline_pl7kmovAHp1svrcsh_540.png"
  data-orig-height="332"
  data-orig-width="1170"
  alt="image"
  style="max-width: 100%">
```

Or CSS:

```
/* On screens that are 1169px or less, set the max-width of img to 100% */
@media screen and (max-width: 1169px) {
  img {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```